# How to connect and create new mail id in exchange mail server using c#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server

I am adding active directory users from c# and I need to create email id for that users using exchange mail server. How to check and create the new mail id's using c#?

Comment: Please add what you have already tried. See this [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, and it's a pain. The only way to programmatically do anything in Exchange is through PowerShell, which means you have to run PowerShell commands from C#.

Ideally, you can open a remote PowerShell session to one of your Exchange servers. Microsoft does have an example of how to do this here: [Get a list of mail users by using the Exchange Management Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/management/how-to-get-a-list-of-mail-users-by-using-the-exchange-management-shell).

Creating the remote PowerShell session would look something like this, which uses Kerberos to authenticate and runs the PowerShell command `Get-Users -ResultSize 10`:

```
var connectionUri = "https://<server>/PowerShell";
var remoteMachineCredentials = new PSCredential(domainAndUserName, securePassword);

WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
        new Uri(connectionUri),
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
        remoteMachineCredentials) {

    AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos,
    SkipRevocationCheck = true
}
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)) {
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {
        powershell.AddCommand("Get-Users");
        powershell.AddParameter("ResultSize", 10);
        runspace.Open();

        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        var results = powershell.Invoke();
        //do something with the results
    }
}
```

You can also use `AuthenticationMechanism.NegotiateWithImplicitCredential` to authenticate with the credentials that your app is running under, if that's what you need.

I use `SkipRevocationCheck = true` to skip the revocation check of the SSL certificate of the server. In my environment, the server I ran this on doesn't have internet access, so the revocation check fails. That may or may not be true for you.

You *can* do it without using remote PowerShell, but it involves installing the Exchange management tools on the computer your app runs on, and there are some other complications. Try to avoid that. Use remote PowerShell if you can.

Once you've figured that out, you can run any PowerShell command, like [`New-Mailbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-mailbox?view=exchange-ps).

You will, of course, want to read the results of your PowerShell response, so there is another article on how to [Use the Exchange Management Shell cmdlet response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/management/how-to-use-the-exchange-management-shell-cmdlet-response).

Be aware that PowerShell errors are not terminating by default (they won't throw an exception), so you have to check if there are errors each time you run a command. To do that, check the [`powershell.Streams.Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatastreams.error?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_PSDataStreams_Error) collection.

Comment: getting error: Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: Oh, you're using Office 365. That's a whole different story. You should ask a new question and show your code.